# Error: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure

Tags: automation, selenium-chromedriver

```
package abc;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class pqr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://demoapp.skillrary.com/");
    }
}
```

This is error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'LAPTOP-LK02MSPR', ip: '192.168.139.118'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at abc.pqr.main(pqr.java:9)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.17.0', revision: 'e52b1be057*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:519)
    ... 7 more
```

I want to run this script and I have been trying in many different ways but due to this exception I have not been able to resolve it.